# Are there rational $a,b$ with $a+be=1/\ln 2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Are there rational $a$ and $b$ with $$a+be = \frac{1}{\ln 2}\ ?$$

I used the absence of rational solutions repeatedly in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429211/44143).

Here is a proof using Schanuel's conjecture: $e^q$ is transcendental for any algebraic $q$ by the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem. In particular $e^q\neq 2$ and $\ln 2$ is irrational. So $1$ and $\ln 2$ are linearly independent over the rationals. Then by Schanuel's conjecture, the set $\{1, \ln 2, e, 2\}$ must have transcendence degree at least $2$ over the rationals, while the above equation would imply that the transcendence degree is only $1$. So there are no rational solutions to the above equation.

Is there a proof without that conjecture?

Comment: "$e^q$ is transcendental for any algebraic $q$" – well, except $q=0$.